# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds after solving 'possible loss of precision' compile error

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

works:meaning no precision error::Just array out of bounds

```
long a[] =new long[1000000];
int no=2,n;
long i;
a[no]=i+a[n];
if(a[no]>longChain)
{
    longChain = a[no];
    startNo = no;
}
```

and when I do

```
long a[] =new long[1000000];
long no=2,n;
long i,longChain=1,startNo;
a[no]=i+a[n];
if(a[no]>longChain)
{
    longChain = a[no];
    startNo = no;
}
```

then loss of precision

found:long

required: int

what is the problem?

My Code  for above problem, its ProjectEuler Problem No. 14

```
class P14
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long a[] =new long[1000000];
        long no=2,n;
        long i,longChain=1,startNo;
        a[1]=1;
        while(no<1000000)
        {
            n=no;
            i=0;
            while(n>no-1)
            {
                if(n%2==0)
                    n=n/2;
                else
                    n=3*n+1;
                i++;
                //System.out.println(n);
            }
            a[no]=i+a[n];
            if (a[no] > longChain)
            {
                longChain=a[no];
                startNo=no;
            }
            no++;
            //System.out.println(no);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for where above problem is occurring

Answer:: Replace a[no] by a[(int)n]

a[n],a[(int)n]

Comment: Please take the time to properly indent your code to make the code blocks formatting work. Right now it's tedious to read your question.

Comment: You can't describe code that gets `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` as working. None of the code you've posted even compiles. Question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: @EJP  no precision errors, thats what I meant by working, but ur right,edited my Q

Comment: 'Compiles' isn't the same as 'working'. Your code still doesn't compile. I suggest you copy-paste your *actual* code, don't try to type it in.

Comment: @EJP I have posted the source code

Comment: @x22 i, n are both initialized, yes its 14 problem of ProjectEuler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your no and n variables need to be int, not long. Arrays can't be indexed by long. Changing the code to:

```
int no=2,n;
```

makes the code compile.

The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is because you wrote the algorithm assuming it was longs.

This code will eventually cause `n` to become negative:

```
n=3*n+1;
```

It's hard to see why when you're doing integer arithmetic.  A slight change to make the code use long arithmetic and print the interim result reveals exactly when it becomes negative and how:

```
while(n>no-1)
{
    long newN = n;

    if (n % 2 == 0) newN = newN / 2L;
    else newN = 3L * newN + 1L;

    if (newN > Integer.MAX_VALUE) System.out.println("about to fail");

    //this is where the magic happens
    n = (int)newN;
    System.out.println("converted " + newN + " to " + n);

    i++;
}
```

Comment: then ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs

Comment: ok, i ll have to use one more variable I suppose, I ll update as I check

Comment: ok, thanks, I used long nL; and then after loop I stored it in n; My program is working!!!

Comment: I've just finished writing up an example of why n becomes negative to further explain what's going on :)

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because array indexing takes an `int` as the index. But all your variables are of type `long`.

```
a[no]
```

`no` is a `long`.

So using `long` as an array index is an implicit downcast which could result in loss of precision.

So either you manually cast it down, or you change `no` to an `int`.

**EDIT: (after additional info in the question)**

I'm not 100% sure if this is the cause:

```
n=3*n+1;
```

You use `n` as in index. But `n` can get pretty large to begin with. So a `*3` could make it larger than the size of the array.

You should probably double-check whatever your algorithm is. (which I can't figure out from the code itself)

Comment: You never initialized `i` and `n`. What are they set to?

Comment: i, n are initialized in a while loop I have posted source code

Comment: yes n ll get very large, but it ll go down below 1000 000 before while loop is exited

Comment: When you get out-of-bounds exception it should tell you what index you tried to access?

Comment: thanks,u were right, n=3*n+1; was the cause, as n become -ve, and exited the while loop, and then tried to stored value at -ve index

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that you cannot store all the possible values you are calculating in array.  Numbers can grow beyond 2^31-1 and you get an overflow.

What you can do is make

```
long n;
```

and

```
while (n > no - 1 || n >= a.length) {

}
// is safe as n < a.length;
a[no] = i + a[(int) n];
```

This ensures you only look up cached values which are inside your array.

Comment: @CoolEulerProject So your array index is out of bounds. So your algorithm is wrong.

Comment: I posted my algo, its ProjectEuler14 problem

Comment: thanks, yes array index increased as n=n*3+1 beyond java array capacity, so I had to replace a[no] by a[(int)no] and a[n] by a[(int)n], as n,no both were long... or use another variable keeping n int

Answer (score 1):

`n` needs to be long because it may get too large for int. (If you use int it will overflow into negative numbers and cause the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.)

You have to declare `n` as `long` and cast it to int when using it as index (`no` can be int)

```
a[no]=i+a[(int)n];
```